# Global KeyBinding to command in the active view's Viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, relaycommand

I have this in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Key="O" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
  <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I have several child views with their own viewmodels. For instance, I have a `FileView` with a `FileViewModel` and a `DataView` with a `DataViewModel`. In both viewmodels I have an implementation of the `OpenCommand`:

```
public ICommand OpenCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (openCommand == null)
        {
            openCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.OpenFile());
        }

        return openCommand;
    }
}
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> I want the `OpenCommand` command to be executed for the active view's viewmodel. Hence, if I press the keys in my `FileView`, `OpenFile()` would be executed. If I enter the keys in my `DataView`, `OpenData()` would be executed. Sort of an `MDI` behavior.

The code above does not work.

**How do you implement this type of keybinding/command handling?**

Comment: Why not add a KeyBinding for the OpenCommand in the FileView as well as in the DataView? It should solve your issue right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a separate implementation for the `OpenCommand` in `FileView` and `DataView`, you should add a `KeyBinding` to these views also.

```
<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="O" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
</Page.InputBindings>
```

or

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="O" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Thanks. But what happens if you press Ctrl+O in some other window? It won't work. E.g. In a tab view, there is a `FileView` and some other views. Ctrl+O should work in the other views too. Do I need to add the command binding to ALL views?

Comment: In your case you have to add KeyBinding in MainWindow, FileView and in DataView.

If Ctrl+O is pressed in some other view, the KeyBinding in MainWindow will be executed. If Ctr+O is pressed in DataView and if DataView has the focus then KeyBinding in DataView will be executed otherwise the KeyBinding in MainWindow will be executed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I realized when I experimented here. Thanks.